# Why does some Windows Updates in wsus doenst contain a architecture?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, wsus, architecture

I synced all security/critical updates on my wsus server and got a lot of updates which doenst contain any architecture. Is this because this update obtains for both architectures (64-bit AND 32-bit). Or if there isnt any architecture does this mean the update is for x86?

A example:

`Update for Windows 7 (KB3020369)`

`Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3020369)`

And another one:

`Security Update for Windows 7 (KB3046002)`

`Security Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB3046002)`

Comment: Not every update necessarily has to contain binary code. Think certificates as an example. They are arch-independent.

Comment: Maybe I understand you wrong, but I almost see no x86 updates in my list with updates. So I was thinking the ones without a architecture would be x86, but i cannot find this anywhere on the internet @Sven

Comment: Maybe add a few example KB numbers to your question ...

Comment: Added 2 exmaples @Sven